# SQL to generate a rowcount for rows during join

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the following output

Table 1

```
transaction id      AppName  
100                    App1  
101                    App2
```

Table 2

```
id   App
1    App1  
2    App1  
3    App1  
4    App2
```

Output table

```
transactionid   AppName    Appcount
100             App1         1  
100             App1         2  
100             App1         3    
101             App2         1
```

The first 2 columns I can get using a join , how can I generate a row count into AppCount for the appNames.

Comment: Please put code and tabular data into code boxes. Furthermore, please show what you have tried so far (i.e. you SQL code) and where it failed. Finally, have a look into the SQL documentation of your RDBMS, especially the aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `join` and `row_number()`:

```
select
    t1.transactionId,
    t1.AppName,
    row_number() over(partition by t1.transactionId order by t2.id) AppCount
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.app = t1.AppName
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.transactionid, t1.appName,
       row_number() over (partition by t1.transactionid order by t2.id) as seqnum
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.appName = t2.appName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ROW_NUMBER()][1]`

```
SELECT T.TransactionID, T.AppName,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITTION BY T.TransactionID ORDER BY S.ID) AppCount
FROM tbl T JOIN tbl 2 S ON T.app = S.AppName
```